# Optimization as sampling for stochastic functions

Tags: machine-learning, sampling, optimization, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

Given an input space $X$ and a function $f: X\rightarrow \mathbb R$, we want to find $x^*=argmin_{x\in X} f(x)$. One way is to cast this problem as a sampling, where we define a distribution $p(x)\propto e^{-f(x)}$. The mode of the distribution corresponds to $x^*$. We can draw $N$ samples from $p(x)$ and pick the one that minimizes $f(x)$ as $x^*$. For example, if we use Metropolis-Hastings algorithm as the sampler, then we are doing something similar to simulated annealing.

However, in my problem, $f(x)$ is stochastic, and we want to find the minimizer in expectation, $x^*=argmin_{x\in X} \mathbb E[f(x)]$. I can evaluate $f(x)$ but it is a quite slow procedure, so I would prefer *not* to e.g. evaluate $f(x)$ 100 times and take the average. In addition, given a specific $y$ from an $f(x)$ evaluation, I don't know its probability mass/density, even up to a constant. Essentially $f(x)$ is just a black-box stochastic procedure that returns a sample after some quite expensive computation.

My question is, can I still use a similar sampling idea for the optimization? A naive way is to pretend that a single $y\sim f(x)$ sample is actually $\mathbb E[f(x)]$, and use that value in the MH-sampler. But I don't know what, if any, distribution is implicitly being sampled.

Another idea is to sample jointly in the $x, y\in X, \mathbb R$ space, but since I can't evaluate the likelihood of $y$, even up to a normalizing constant, under $f(x)$, and running $f(x)$ multiple times is perhaps too expensive, I don't know how to write a sampler with this constraint.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is perhaps worth noting that this bears many similarities with the setting where $f$ is a sum of many terms, i.e. $f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^N f_i (x)$, and one estimates $f$ by sampling a subset of these terms; this is roughly how stochastic gradient descent works. There are possibly useful ideas in this literature which could be useful.

Comment: Some small clarifying questions: i) is your space $X$ structured in some way? e.g. is it a subset of $\mathbf{R}^d$, or is it discrete, or something else? ii) is your function $f$ structured in some way? e.g. bounded above, smooth, etc. Even quite basic structures like this can be useful in working out which algorithmic approaches are available.

Comment: @πr8 For your questions, in my case $X$ is a discrete combinatorial space, which is why I am thinking about the sampling approach rather than gradient descent. $f$ is bounded above and below, so I can normalize it, and thus the expectation as well, to 0 and 1 very easily. But I am not sure how they help in this specific case.

Comment: A paper from this morning (https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.00234) addresses roughly your problem, and may be of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand upon the solution which is hinted at in the answer of @Xi'an:

Assume that $f$ is represented as

$$f(x) = \mathbf{E}_{\rho(\xi)} \left[ F(x, \xi) \right]$$

where $\xi$ is some auxiliary source of randomness, and $0 \leqslant F(x, \xi) \leqslant 1$ for all $(x, \xi)$.

One can then develop

\begin{align}
\exp(-\beta f(x)) &= \exp \left( -\beta \right) \cdot \exp \left(\beta \left\{1 - f(x) \right\} \right) \\
&= \sum_{n \geqslant 0} \frac{\beta^n e^{-\beta}}{n!} \left\{1 - f(x) \right\}^n \\
&= \mathbf{E}_{N \sim \text{Po}(\beta)} \left[ \left\{1 - f(x) \right\}^N \right] \\
&= \mathbf{E}_{N \sim \text{Po}(\beta)} \left[ \prod_{a = 1}^N \mathbf{E}_{\rho(\xi^a)} \left[ 1 - F \left(x, \xi^a \right) \right] \right].
\end{align}

This implies that if we write down the joint distribution

$$ \Pi \left( x, N, \{ \xi^a \}_{a = 1}^N \right) \propto \frac{\beta^N e^{-\beta}}{N!} \cdot \prod_{a = 1}^N \left\{ \rho(\xi^a) \left[ 1 - F \left(x, \xi^a \right) \right] \right\},$$

then the $x$-marginal is given by $\mu_\beta (x) \propto \exp(-\beta f(x))$.

This enables the application of a Pseudo-Marginal Metropolis-Hastings MCMC algorithm. Consider the proposal

$$Q \left( (x, N, \Xi) \to (x', N', \Xi') \right) = q ( x \to x' ) \cdot \text{Po} ( N' | \beta ) \cdot \prod_{b = 1}^{N'} \rho ( \xi'^b ).$$

Working through the details, one can compute that the Metropolis-Hastings ratio simplifies to

$$r \left( (x, N, \Xi) \to (x', N', \Xi') \right) = \frac{q ( x' \to x )}{q ( x \to x' )} \cdot \frac{ \prod_{b = 1}^{N'} \left[ 1 - F \left(x, \xi'^b \right) \right] }{ \prod_{a = 1}^N \left[ 1 - F \left(x, \xi^a \right) \right]}$$

which can be computed exactly, allowing for a tractable Metropolis-Hastings correction. This means that one can generate a Markov chain with $\Pi \left( x, N, \Xi \right)$ as its invariant measure, and hence the $x$-marginal of the chain will converge to $\mu_\beta$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I have two questions. 1. Can you tell me which identity you used to derive the 2nd line in the multi-line equation? 2. As I understand, the last equation defines the transition probability. I can define a transition kernel on $X$, with probability $q(x'\rightarrow x)$ and $q(x\rightarrow x')$, but how should I choose a transition kernel for $N$ and $\Xi$? Are $N$ and $N'$ sampled from $\mathrm{Po}(\beta)$, and $\xi$ implicit when I evaluate the stochastic $F(x, \xi)$? Given that each $F(x, \xi)$ evaluation is time-consuming, can I force $N=1$ throughout?

Comment: The 2nd line in the equation comes from the Taylor expansion of the function $x \mapsto \exp(x)$. The generation of $(N, \Xi)$ are sampled implicitly, as you say. You cannot force $N = 1$ and still get the correct invariant measure; it is important that $N$ can become arbitrarily large. If $F$ is expensive to evaluate, then perhaps there are other structures which you can exploit - can you give more information about $F$?

Comment: I see. Thanks for your reply. In my case, $F$ is the validation accuracy of a deep neural network trained on some data, and $X$ is the hyper-parameter space. So I am essentially trying to find the best hyper-parameter setting that achieves on average best validation accuracy. The stochasticity comes from the random seed and architectural randomness (e.g. dropout). So I don't think there are more insights that can be exploited.

Comment: By the way, I am aware of other techniques such as Bayesian optimization, but I am just wondering if this hyper-parameter search can be approached from this sampling perspective, which is really flexible and does not depend on having a parametric representation of the mapping from the hyper-parameter space to the validation accuracy (as does by e.g. Gaussian process regression).

Comment: Understood. I think in this setting, if you're set on doing something like simulated annealing, it would be a reasonable idea to just do a biased estimate of $\exp(-\beta f(x))$. You will not get the same asymptotic guarantees, but the algorithm may nevertheless be useful.

Comment: Yes, thanks again for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very interesting question for which there is no clear-cut answer. It all depends on the computing budget and the output of a realistic will depend on this computing budget.

My suggestion would be to mix

(i) simulated annealing, that is, simulating from a target like $$h_t(x)\propto e^{-T_t \cdot \mathbb E[f(x)]}\qquad T_t \uparrow \infty$$
where the temperature $T_t$ is slowing increasing with $t$,

(ii) [pseudo-marginal Metropolis-Hastings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-marginal_Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm), when the value of the target is replaced with an unbiased estimate at each iteration, and

(iii) [debiasing à la Glynn and Rhee](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eglynn/papers/2015/RheeG15.html), as in [Russian roulette](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/tag/russian-roulette/) estimators, where a converging sequence of biased estimators, $\hat\eta_n$ is turned into a unbiased estimator
$$\sum_{n=1}^G \{\eta_{n+1}-\eta_n\}/\mathbb P(G\ge n)$$
$G$ being a integer valued random variable (like a Poisson). This last step involves computing a random number $G$ of realisations of $f(x)$.

An alternative is to use [stochastic optimisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_approximation), by considering the sequence $(X_n)_n$ such that
$$X_{n+1}=X_n-\epsilon_n \nabla f(X_n)\qquad \epsilon_n\downarrow 0$$
where $\nabla f$ denotes a realisation of the gradient of $f$, i.e.
$$\mathbb E[\nabla f(X_n] = \nabla \mathbb E[f(X_n]]$$
If this is impossible to obtain, a finite difference approach is the [Kiefer-Wolfowitz algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_approximation#Kiefer%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_algorithm)
$$X_{n+1}=X_n-\epsilon_n \dfrac{f(X_n+\upsilon_n)-f(X_n-\upsilon_n)}{2\upsilon_n}\qquad \epsilon_n,\upsilon_n\downarrow 0$$